# Iframe content does not load in Html widget in Flutter

Tags: html, flutter, iframe, flutter-html

I am using Html Widget to show article content in Flutter andriod app.Content is mixed html tag and contains some video embeded using iframe. Widget display a loading circle for a few seconds and after that nothing shown.

Flutter version 3.3.3

flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6

Sample Code expected to show in app:

```
<h3>View more</h3>
<p>This is a sample code for article and video inside artcle body</p>
<div class="h_iframe-aparat_embed_frame"><span style="display: block;padding-top: 57%"></span><iframe src="https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/q0IdU/vt/frame" allowFullScreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe></div>
<p>Click to view more video</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

```
 var html = '''
       <iframe width="1200" height='710'
        src="$videosid" </iframe>
   ''';

  Column(children:[
         **HtmlWidget(html)** OR
         InAppWebView(
                     InAppWebViewInitialData(data: '${html}'),
                     initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                     url: Uri.parse("${videosid}" ?? ''),
                      ),
                     ),
        ] 
       )
```